# Add stats to "less info" on users profile page

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, statistics, user-information, personal-statistics

I like the "less info" option on the users profile page. But I'm missing the stats (flag weight, profile views) region. All other regions (bio, visits) are present.

Would it be possible to include the stats also in this view? Maybe the flag weight is enough to include for stats.

Comment: There are other fields that are not shown in "less info." You prefer to see those fields; somebody else prefers to see other fields. How are you going to make users agree with requiring the same fields to be shown in the "less info" view?